# User Management and Privileges with Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, acl, fosuserbundle

I wonder if there's a powerfull tool in Symfony2 to manage the privileges and rights of users in the same fashion as Facebook.

I have read the tutorial about ACL/ACE but I would like to grant/revoke rights to a group not only to a single user.

For example a user can set many groups (family, work, etc.) and permits to some of them to get access to a resource (image, album, sensitive data like the birthday etc.)

Thank's,